# redirect to profile after creating a user which auto create a profile

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-urls

Apologize for being annoying,I'm a beginner programmer and working on my new project.

I've made this model which create a profile when a user is created:

```
class ExpertSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

@transaction.atomic
def save(self):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.is_expert = True
    user.save()
    expert = Expert.objects.create(expert=user)
    return user
```

and this is the view. So what i am trying to do here is to sign a user then set his premission as a expert and then log him in which i've already done but what I'm not able to do is to redirect him into his expert details/update profile right after logging in .
so if you can help me with that. Thank you in advance.

Here are the views:

```
class ExpertSignUpView(CreateView):
        model = User
        form_class = ExpertSignUpForm
        template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            kwargs['user_type'] = 'expert'
            return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        def form_valid(self, form):
            user = form.save()
            login(self.request, user)
            return redirect('/') <<-------
```

the urls might help

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',ExpertListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('Esignup/',ExpertSignUpView.as_view(), name='expert_signup'),
    path('Ssignup/',StudentSignUpView.as_view(), name='student_signup'),
    path('create/',ExpertCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('<str:pk>/',ExpertDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<str:pk>/update/',ExpertUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('<str:pk>/delete/',ExpertDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try changing the urlpatterns so that the most restrictive is processed first

```
urlpatterns = [  
    path('Esignup/',ExpertSignUpView.as_view(), name='expert_signup'),
    path('Ssignup/',StudentSignUpView.as_view(), name='student_signup'),
    path('create/',ExpertCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('<str:pk>/',ExpertDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<str:pk>/update/',ExpertUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('<str:pk>/delete/',ExpertDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
    path('',ExpertListView.as_view(), name='list'),
]
```

Then in your redirect give the path expression you want to go to

```
return redirect('app_name:update')
```

Comment: thanks for your help IndikaM. but now i get( Reverse for 'update' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profiles/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update/$']) and then tried to ad pk=pk as an argument after the profiles:update and got (name 'pk' is not defined) error if you could help me further thank you in advance

Comment: in url's
    path('/details/<str:pk>',ExpertDetailView.as_view(), name='detail')

in the view
    return redirect('detail', pk=user)